# PowerMock throw initialzationError when a class's static method return same a same class's object

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, mockstatic

An `initializationError` is thrown. I'm using powermock 1.6.4 and javassist-3.20.0. It seems I can't mock and mockstatic on the same class (at the same time).

```
interface B
{
  public static B getA()
  {
    return new B()
      {
      };
  }
}

a test code is:
@PrepareForTest({B.class})
@Test
  public void testB()
  {
    B a = mock( B.class );
    mockStatic( B.class );
    when( B.getA() ).thenReturn( a );

  }
```

Comment: Where is the error thrown?
Please include what you have tried so far to resolve this problem.

Comment: There is no any error thrown , neither Failure Trace. If I use a BFactory and the code like:  B a = mock(B.class); mockStatic(BFactory.class); when(BFactory.getA()).thenRturn(a); then it works fine, but I do not want to add a Factory just for this mock test purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepare the `B` mock (by, for example, using `PowerMockRunner`) otherwise the test will throw a `ClassNotPreparedException` at this line:

```
mockStatic( B.class );
```

This test will pass (though since it has no assertions it might be more accurate to say that this test will not throw an exception ;):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({B.class})
public class BTest {

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        B a = Mockito.mock(B.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
        Mockito.when(B.getA()).thenReturn(a);
    }
}
```

I have verified this using:

- Mockito v1.10.19 with PowerMock v1.6.4
- Mockito v2.7.19 with PowerMock v1.7.0